# I want to create a random sample of length n from a normal multivariate distribution

Tags: statistics

This may sound like a stupid question, but I have a problem in understanding this question, especially this part:

"generate a random sample of length n from a normal multivariate"

This is what I have done using the R package mvtnorm:

```
my_function <- function(n=1,k){
mean = rep(0,k)
sigma = diag(length(mean))
rmvnorm(n, mean, sigma,method=c("eigen", "svd", "chol"), pre0.9_9994 = FALSE)}

using_rmvnorm(3)
```

This way the output of my function is, in this example, a vector of three numbers which in my mind is a sample of length 3. Is this correct? Is there another way to do this?

I am asking this question because I have to do the same without using the library rmvnorm and with a normal bivariate.

I just managed to write the density function:

```
dbivnorm <- function(x,y,mux=0,muy=0,sigmax=1,sigmay=1,rho=0){
  (2*pi)^(-1) * ((1-rho^2)*sigmax^2*sigmay^2)^(-.5) *
    exp( -((x-mux)^2/(sigmax^2) -2*rho*((x-mux)/sigmax *(y-muy)/sigmay) +
             (y-muy)^2/(sigmay^2))/(2*(1-rho^2)) )
}
```

But now I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: If you don't get good responses here, you could try Stats SE or SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *Mathematica*:

```
n = 4;
RandomVariate[
 MultinormalDistribution[ConstantArray[0, n], IdentityMatrix[n]], 3]
```

Comment: So in your case n = 4 is the length of the sample and 3 is the number of samples you wanted to generate?